# C# MVC API Data Transfer Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dto

I am hoping to get a bit of advice into an issue im facing with converting my current setup to one that incorporates DTO's.  What im trying to do is get a specific user based on their user code.  But im coming up against a problem in the LINQ expression

```
.AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.uCode == code);
```

It is throwing this problem....

```
cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.ienumerable<DataModel.UserDTO>to'DataModel.Users'. An explicit conversion exists
```

My Method:

```
[Route("api/Usr/{usrCode}")]
public User GetUser(string code)
{
    return db.Users.Select(s => new UserDTO
    {
        uid = s.uid,
        firstName = s.firstName,
        lastName = s.lastName,
        email = s.emailAddress,
        area = s.areaId,
        uCode = s.uCode
     }).AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.uCode == code);
}
```

My DTO:

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public int uid { get; set; }
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    public String dob {get; set;}
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String profile { get; set; }
    public String uCode { get; set; }
    public int areaId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: change method return type from ``User`` to ``IEnumerable<UserDTO>`` as you are returning collection

Comment: Firstly your query returns a collection, not a single object (you need to use `FirstOrDefault()`. Next it generates a `UserDTO` but your method returns type of `User` (they are not the same)

Answer (score 1):

Your method expects one entity to be returned. So use `First` method to take first occurrence with given code

```
public UserDTO GetUser(string code)
{
    var user = db.Users.First(x=>x.uCode ==code);
    return new UserDTO
    {
      uid = s.uid,
      firstName = s.firstName,
      lastName = s.lastName,
      email = s.emailAddress,
      area = s.areaId,
      uCode = s.uCode
    };
 }
```

And you have to convert your dto to domain object.
Take into account: that better to filter domain objects first and only after that create a DTOs.

Comment: The method also needs to be changed to `public UserDTO GetUser(string code)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thx, I haven't paid attentions to different types.

Answer (score 1):

The Where method returns an IEnumerable of your model but you only want a single one. You can use First or, perhaps better, FirstOrDefault() to get a single object.

Additionally, the return type on your action method is wrong and calling .AsEnumerable will bring *all* the data back from the database.

Also, you use usrCode as your route value but code as your action param.

So, in sum, your method should look like this:

```
[Route("api/Usr/{code}")]
public UserDTO GetUser(string code)
{
    return db.Users.Where(a => a.uCode == code).Select(s => new UserDTO
    {
        uid = s.uid,
        firstName = s.firstName,
        lastName = s.lastName,
        email = s.emailAddress,
        area = s.areaId,
        uCode = s.uCode
     }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query to the database is not correct. First it'll be better to filter values before mapping and then map only filtered user. Next you should retrieve only first user. The optimal query will be:

```
public UserDTO GetUser(string code)
{
    return db.Users
             .Where(user => user.uCode == code)
             .Take(1)
             .Select(s => new UserDTO
                    {
                        uid = s.uid,
                        firstName = s.firstName,
                        lastName = s.lastName,
                        email = s.emailAddress,
                        area = s.areaId,
                        uCode = s.uCode
                    })
            .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This query will translate to the SQL code:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    uid = u.uid,
    firstName = u.firstName,
    lastName = u.lastName,
    email = u.emailAddress,
    area = u.areaId,
    uCode = u.uCode
FROM
    Users u
WHERE
    u.uCode = @code
```

Then if you have few users with same code you'll retrieve only 1 from the server.